# How to detect/find particular layout is used in which slides using VBA in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How to find particular layout name/index is used by which slides? 
As i want to delete some layouts from my theme which are already used by some slides. and apply the new one from them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debug.Print ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout.Name

You can't delete any layouts that are in use by slides.  You need to apply a different layout to any such slides, THEN delete the layout.

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down ... though the question may not show a lot of previous research, it poses a valid problem; the answer's marked as "not useful".  Why?  It answers the question, it's accurate.  What's the problem?

Comment: I'm only guessing but I'd say the lack of any demonstrable effort to solve himself, especially in light of his last question where he was given code to set a layout on a slide.

Comment: That seems to be the complaint about the question (though both that one and the other q appeared at about the same time).  On the other hand, the answer to the question isn't obvious; simply leaving it marked as answered might be of benefit to someone else who's trying to find the same answer.  Denigrating both the question and the answer would put someone off the track (and might lead to them asking the same question over again ... waste of everybody's time).  O well.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg : Thanks for the support for my question. I  discoverd the other way to solved my own problem. I will post the answer after the complition of my project. Because my competitor also follow my post on stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the slide layout you want to get rid of, draw a big red X on that layout, then go back to normal view and you can easily see which slides have that particular layout as they will all show a big red X.  Change these slides to a different layout and then you can delete the layout you don't want.